# Standard Deviation

Tags: math-mode

I have my code for standard deviation formula as follow:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{makeidx}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  

\begin{document}  
\[ t=\dfrac{\overline{X}_{1}-\overline{X}_{2}}  
{\sqrt{\dfrac{\left\lbrace\Sigma X_{1}^{2} \dfrac{\left( \Sigma  
 X_{1}\right)^{2}}{N_{1}}\right\rbrace+\left\lbrace\Sigma X_{2}^{2}   
 \dfrac{\left(\Sigma X_{2}\right)^{2}}{N_{2}}\right\rbrace}  
 {N_{1}+N_{2}-2}\text{x}\left( \dfrac{N_{1}+N_{2}}{N_{1}N_{2}} \right)}} \]  
\end{document}
```

It looks complicated. Is there any simple way to make the same formula?

Comment: I'd start by replacing all instances of `\Sigma` with `\sum` and replacing `\text{x}` with `\times`.

Comment: As it stands the only \usepackage you need is {amsmath} the others would be needed for other uses such as graphics, However If it works it is good enough as it is. You could try building definitions for common parts if there were thousands of similar formulaic blocks but for a one off formula off why? If you want other tex users to see the breakdown of what each part does you could separate it with descriptive comments between the parts

Comment: you could remove some of the superfluous braces so the first part becomes simply \dfrac{\overline X_1-\overline X_2}

Comment: It's a nasty formula to begin with.  After the previous comments, you could simplify the expression by getting rid of the complex fraction, but that would make the resulting formula harder to understand.  (Shouldn't the denominator be `\sum X_1^2 minus \dfrac...`?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I must confess I'm not sure if your formula is correct. For sure, the formula does *not* denote a *standard deviation*, as would appear to be implied by your query. Instead, it appears to be an expression for the *t-test* of the null hypothesis that two population means are equal, assuming the draws are iid (independently and identically distributed).

The following screenshot reproduces your original formula in the first row, a typographically simplified version of that formula, in which I've replaced all instances of `\Sigma` with `\sum`, in the second row, and what I believe to be the standard form of the t-test in the third row. For what it's worth, it's the formula I learned in an econometrics course while in grad school, many years ago. And, I daresay, the formula in the third row is easier to read and parse than those in rows 1 and 2...

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}    
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for 'align*' env.

\begin{document}  
\noindent
We wish to test the null hypothesis that the means of two populations are equal. 
Denote the observations drawn from the two populations by $X_{1i}$ and~$X_{2j}$, 
with $i=1,\dots,N_1$ and $j=1,\dots,N_2$. Let 
\[
\bar{X}_1=\frac{1}{N_1}\sum_{i=1}^{N_1} X_{1i} 
\quad\text{and}\quad
\bar{X}_2=\frac{1}{N_2}\sum_{j=1}^{N_2} X_{2j}
\] 
denote the sample means, and let 
\[
\hat{\sigma}_1^2=\frac{1}{N_1-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N_1} (X_{1i} -\bar{X}_1)^2 
\quad\text{and}\quad
\hat{\sigma}_2^2=\frac{1}{N_2-1}\sum_{j=1}^{N_2} (X_{2j} -\bar{X}_2)^2
\] 
denote the sample variances. If the observations are iid, 
the $t$-test of the null hypothesis is given by
\begin{align*}
t&=\dfrac{\overline{X}_{1}-\overline{X}_{2}}  
{\sqrt{\dfrac{
\left\lbrace\Sigma X_{1}^{2} 
\dfrac{\left( \Sigma X_{1}\right)^{2}}{N_{1}}\right\rbrace
+\left\lbrace\Sigma X_{2}^{2}
\dfrac{\left(\Sigma X_{2}\right)^{2}}{N_{2}}\right\rbrace}  
 {N_{1}+N_{2}-2}\text{x}
 \left( \dfrac{N_{1}+N_{2}}{N_{1}N_{2}} \right)}} \\
&=\frac{\bar{X}_1-\bar{X}_2}{\displaystyle
\Biggl[\frac{
\sum X_1^2 \frac{ (\sum X_1)^2}{N_1}+\sum X_2^2   
    \frac{ (\sum X_2)^2}{N_2}}{N_1+N_2-2}
    \times \frac{N_1+N_2}{N_1N_2}
\Biggr]^{1/2}} \\
&=\frac{\bar{X}_1-\bar{X}_2}{\displaystyle
\biggl[
\frac{(N_1-1)\hat{\sigma}_1^2 + (N_2-1)\hat{\sigma}_2^2}{N_1+N_2-2}
\biggl(\frac{1}{N_1}+\frac{1}{N_2}\biggr)
\biggr]^{1/2}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

In statistics, we can calculate two types of standard deviation.

For Population S.D:

```
\begin{equation}
\sigma = \sqrt\frac{\sum{(X-\mu)^2}}{N}
\end{equation}
```

where,

```
$\sigma$ = Population S.D.  

X = is individual value  

$\mu$ = Population Mean  

N = Population size
```

For Sample S.D., however, we have a slightly differnt formula:

```
\begin{equation}
s = \sqrt\frac{\sum{(x_i-\bar{x})^2}}{n-1}
\end{equation}
```

where

```
*s* = Sample S.D.
$x_i$ = individual value
$\bar{x}$ = Sample mean
n = Sample size
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Your answer doesn't quite read like it's responding to the question, but more like you're writing a short blog post about the standard deviation.  I would also recommend `{}` around the radicand of the `\sqrt`.  (That's my best guess for why someone else downvoted your answer.)